How to detect KeyRelease .NET MAUI MacCatalyst
So I am making game in .NET MAUI for MacOS. I Cant figure out how to change global variable Globals.SpeedX back to 0 after left or right arrow key release. This is my code but the method OnReleaseKey() is never called so it doesnt work. Can someone help??

    private void SetupKeyboardListener()
    {
#if MACCATALYST
    var nativeWindow = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    if (nativeWindow != null)
    {
        nativeWindow.RootViewController.View.AddSubview(new KeyResponder(OnLeftArrowKeyPressed, OnRightArrowKeyPressed, OnCKeyPressed, OnVKeyPressed, OnKeyReleased));
    }
#endif
    }

    private void OnLeftArrowKeyPressed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Left arrow pressed");
        Globals.PlayerSpeedX = -1;
    }

    private void OnRightArrowKeyPressed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Right arrow pressed");
        Globals.PlayerSpeedX = 1;
    }

    private void OnKeyReleased()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key released");
        Globals.PlayerSpeedX = 0;
    }
}

public class KeyResponder : UIView
{
    private readonly Action onLeftArrowKeyPressed;
    private readonly Action onRightArrowKeyPressed;
    private readonly Action onCKeyPressed;
    private readonly Action onVKeyPressed;
    private readonly Action onKeyReleased;

    public KeyResponder(Action onLeftArrowKeyPressed, Action onRightArrowKeyPressed, Action onCKeyPressed, Action onVKeyPressed, Action onKeyReleased)
    {
        this.onLeftArrowKeyPressed = onLeftArrowKeyPressed;
        this.onRightArrowKeyPressed = onRightArrowKeyPressed;
        this.onCKeyPressed = onCKeyPressed;
        this.onVKeyPressed = onVKeyPressed;
        this.onKeyReleased = onKeyReleased;

        Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds; // Rozprostřeme přes celé okno
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;   // Průhledné pozadí
        BecomeFirstResponder();
    }

    public override bool CanBecomeFirstResponder => true;

    public override void PressesBegan(NSSet<UIPress> presses, UIPressesEvent evt)
    {
        foreach (UIPress press in presses)
        {
            if (press.Key != null)
            {
                switch (press.Key.KeyCode)
                {
                    case UIKeyboardHidUsage.KeyboardLeftArrow:
                        onLeftArrowKeyPressed?.Invoke();
                        break;

                    case UIKeyboardHidUsage.KeyboardRightArrow:
                        onRightArrowKeyPressed?.Invoke();
                        break;

                    case UIKeyboardHidUsage.KeyboardC:
                        onCKeyPressed?.Invoke();
                        break;

                    case UIKeyboardHidUsage.KeyboardV:
                        onVKeyPressed?.Invoke();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        base.PressesBegan(presses, evt);
    }

    public override void PressesEnded(NSSet<UIPress> presses, UIPressesEvent evt)
    {
        foreach (UIPress press in presses)
        {
            if (press.Key != null)
            {
                switch (press.Key.KeyCode)
                {
                    case UIKeyboardHidUsage.KeyboardLeftArrow:
                    case UIKeyboardHidUsage.KeyboardRightArrow:
                        onKeyReleased?.Invoke();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        base.PressesEnded(presses, evt);
    }
}

I have tried many implementations of how to detect key pressed. This one was the only one working for MacCatalyst. By working I mean KeyPressed are working however KeyReleased doesnt work for some reason.

this is a know issue in Maui check https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9281
